# Generating an SAS Token in Java to download a file in an Azure Data Storage container

Tags: java, rest, azure, azure-storage

Trying to generate an SAS Token to access certain files in a Storage Account.  I'm using the methods listed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token

Now, the problem I have is I cannot, for the life of me, make the sasToken string work.  If I generate the token via the Portal (Shared Access Signature in the Storage Account), I can access those files via a URL with the provided Token.

However I have yet to be able to generate an SAS token programmatically via Java using the methods I linked above.  I think my problem is the StringToSign that is being encrypted.  I've been following this example when constructing the string to encrypt:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/constructing-an-account-sas

All my efforts have resulted in either:

```
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature fields not well formed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
```

or

```
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was <insert string details here>
```

Looking at the Portal generated sasToken that works for me:

?sv=2017-11-09&ss=f&srt=o&sp=r&se=2018-12-06T22:15:20Z&st=2018-12-06T14:15:20Z&spr=https&sig=%2Bi1TWv5D80U%2BoaIeoBh1wjaO1p4xVFx4nRZt%2FzwiszY%3D

It seems I need a String like so:

```
            String stringToSign = accountName + "\n" +
                "r\n" +
                "f\n" +
                "o\n" +
                URLEncoder.encode(start, "UTF-8") + "\n" +
                URLEncoder.encode(expiry, "UTF-8") + "\n" +
                "\n" +
                "https\n" +
                azureApiVersion;
```

Where accountName is the storage account name from Azure, and start/expiry are the start and expiry strings (ie- 2018-12-06T22:15:20Z) and azureApiVersion is "2017-11-09".

I then try to return the token after constructing the string like so:

```
        String signature = getHMAC256(key, stringToSign);
        sasToken = "sv=" + azureApiVersion +
                "&ss=f" +
                "&srt=o" +
                "&sp=r" +
                "&se=" +URLEncoder.encode(expiry, "UTF-8") +
                "&st=" + URLEncoder.encode(start, "UTF-8") +
                "&spr=https" +
                "&sig=" + URLEncoder.encode(signature, "UTF-8");
```

I've tried URL encoding and not URL encoding the the start/expiry dates as well, just in case that was messing things up.  What am I missing?

Comment: What is the value of key you’re using? Is it the string you got from portal or a byte array got by base64 decoding the account key string?

Comment: The value of my key is one of the Access keys on the Storage Account in Azure.

Comment: I believe the problem is in your `getHMAC256` method. I looked up the code for it and it is simply getting the bytes from string value. Actually you would need to base64 decode the key string and use that byte array in this method.

Comment: Okay, I tried changing the base getHMAC256 method to use:

    SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(key), "HmacSHA256");

And unfortunately got back the "Signature did not match. String to sign used was <etc. etc. etc.>" message.

Comment: @seanDematic I'm getting the same error? Were you able to resolved it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three points to fix

1. `getHMAC256` method problem as mentioned by @Gaurav
2. Don't encode `expiry` and `start` in `stringToSign` or the signature won't match. Because the encoded part in url will be decoded by Azure Storage Service to calculate the expected signature.
3. In `stringToSign`, miss one `\n` after `azureApiVersion`.

Here's the complete sample.

```
 public static void GetFileSAS(){

    String accountName = "accountName";
    String key = "accountKey";
    String resourceUrl = "https://"+accountName+".file.core.windows.net/fileShare/fileName";

    String start = "startTime";
    String expiry = "expiry";
    String azureApiVersion = "2017-11-09";

    String stringToSign = accountName + "\n" +
                "r\n" +
                "f\n" +
                "o\n" +
                start + "\n" +
                expiry + "\n" +
                "\n" +
                "https\n" +
                azureApiVersion+"\n";

    String signature = getHMAC256(key, stringToSign);

    try{

        String sasToken = "sv=" + azureApiVersion +
            "&ss=f" +
            "&srt=o" +
            "&sp=r" +
            "&se=" +URLEncoder.encode(expiry, "UTF-8") +
            "&st=" + URLEncoder.encode(start, "UTF-8") +
            "&spr=https" +
            "&sig=" + URLEncoder.encode(signature, "UTF-8");

    System.out.println(resourceUrl+"?"+sasToken);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String getHMAC256(String accountKey, String signStr) {
    String signature = null;
    try {
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(accountKey), "HmacSHA256");
        Mac sha256HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        sha256HMAC.init(secretKey);
        signature = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256HMAC.doFinal(signStr.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return signature;
}
```

Comment: Doh!  You're absolutely right with points 1 and 3 (I was trying with the dates encoded and not encoded and just happened to paste in the encoded version in my example)

Thanks!

Comment: In addition to the above - I found this section useful in describing whats going in with `stringToSign`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/constructing-an-account-sas#constructing-the-signature-string

Comment: I've ran into an issue with this where the download link just wouldn't expire. Turns out, my browser was caching the result from the request. Trying the link in another browser proved it was really expired. See this : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f56174cb-f0a9-4aba-83de-db7fef748b37/blob-sas-does-not-expire?forum=windowsazuredata. Just putting this out there...

Answer (score 3):

I got a simpler method

```
SharedAccessAccountPolicy sharedAccessAccountPolicy = new SharedAccessAccountPolicy();
sharedAccessAccountPolicy.setPermissionsFromString("racwdlup");
long date = new Date().getTime();
long expiryDate = new Date(date + 8640000).getTime();
sharedAccessAccountPolicy.setSharedAccessStartTime(new Date(date));
sharedAccessAccountPolicy.setSharedAccessExpiryTime(new Date(expiryDate));
sharedAccessAccountPolicy.setResourceTypeFromString("sco");
sharedAccessAccountPolicy.setServiceFromString("bfqt");
String sasToken = "?" + storageAccount.generateSharedAccessSignature(sharedAccessAccountPolicy);
```

You can get the storage account like this:

```
private String storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storage name>;AccountKey=<your key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
```

Comment: hey where can I get SharedAccessAccountPolicy library in mvn?

Comment: @Rodolfo Velasco I think it was this one.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage
Let me know if this does not work I will check.

Comment: Ok I checked anyways. Here it is:
compile group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-storage', version: '8.0.0'
I used v8.0.0 on maven I see they have newer versions.

Comment: I used the last version at this point in time. I need to set permissions just to read(download), so I changed "racwdlup" to "r". Besides that do you think is needed to change anything in setResourceTypeFromString("sco") or setServiceFromString("bfqt")?. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: @Rodolfo Velasco I honestly do not remember how this permissions work on Azure anymore, but there was an explanation in their docs.